# How to increment version number according to last approved iOS version

Tags: fastlane

I know that there is `increment_version_number` lane, but it increments version that is placed in `Info.plist` file. It means that after every uploading to TestFlight developer have to update `Info.plist` file with new version.

Also, Fastlane has `get_version_number` lane but I could not get to make my script work, because it can't increment version like 2.4.1 with the last digit.

So, how I could make +1 (to last digit) to approved version in TestFlight, which is currently 2.4.1 ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have an existing upload in Testflight for an app, you have to increment either the `Version number` or the `Build number` (or both).

The `Version number` can be incremented automatically with `increment_version_number` (as you noted), but you should specify what to increment.
In your case (v2.4.1): the major version number is 2, the minor is 4, the patch is 1.

So you should add this snippet in the `Fastfile` before building/archiving the app:

```
increment_version_number(
  bump_type: "patch"
)
```

However I would not recommend to set version numbers automatically because the app’s version number depends on what you provide in the update. If it’s just a bug fix release or performance optimisation then increment the last digit the `patch`. If you’ve added some cool new features, you should increment the `minor` version. If the update was like a rewrite from scratch, a full redesign or some breaking change introduced then I would increment the `major` number in the version. It’s not elegant to always increment the `patch` number because the version number has a meaning.

In the project I’m working on we used to bump the version numbers manually upon a release, but increment the `Build numbers` automatically with Fastlane.

**Here is what we did:**

1.) Enable Apple Generic Versioning in the project: (Project > Build Settings > Versioning > Versioning System: Apple Generic)

2.) Set base build number: (Project > Build Settings > Versioning > Current Project Version: 1)

3.) Add the following simple Ruby helper class to fastlane/utility folder:

changelog_helpers.rb:

```
class BuildNumberFactory
  class << self
    def make
      `git rev-list HEAD --count`
    end
  end
end
```

4.) Add this line to the very first lines in `Fastfile`:

```
Dir.glob('./utility/*').each { |file| require file }
```

5.) Usage in `FastFile`:

```
lane :your_submit_testflight_lane do
    increment_build_number build_number: BuildNumberFactory.make
    # gym, pilot, other actions after setting the build number
end
```

This method assumes that you use Git for version control. Basically for each commit Fastlane can assign a specific build number. And since you upload apps with incrementing `Build number`, it won’t be a problem that `Version number` is not changing.

**When you’re about to release an update for the app I would suggest to:**

1.) Increment the `Version number` (e.x. `2.4.2`) in a new commit, push it to remote

2.) Create a Git tag for that commit

3.) Run your Fastlane lane which uploads the builds to Testflight

With the above technic, developers will not have to update Info.plist `Version number` all the time when submitting daily test builds to Testflight. 
You only have to increment the `Version number` when you release an update - you can’t avoid this anyway.

Hope it helps! :)